# Contact form with email selection

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

i have a contact form who need to select one email from a  select list, when an user try to send an email there are no error but the email is not sended.

The controller code is:

```
public function contact(){
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->library('email');

        if(isset($_POST['act']) && $_POST['act'] =="act"){
              $name = $_POST['name'];
              $email   = $_POST['email'];
              $phone = $_POST['phone'];
              $message = $_POST['message'];

              $interested = $_POST['interested'];
              if ($interested == 'info') { 
                $to = 'xxx@xxx.org';
                }
                    else if ($interested == 'job') { 
                    $to = 'xxx@xx3.com'; 
                    }
                    else if ($interested == 'project'){
                        $to = 'xxx@xxx1.it';
                    }

              $this->load->library('email');
              $this->email->from($email, $name, $phone);
              $this->email->to($to); 
              $this->email->subject($interested);
              $this->email->message($message);  
              $this->email->send();

                redirect('Welcome/index');
          }
    }
```

And this is my View code:

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
                <form method="post" role="form" action="<?php echo site_url('welcome/contact'); ?>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="act" value="act"/>
                    <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <p> Scegli a chi inviare la mail:</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <div class="form-group">
                            <select class="form-control m-b" id="interested" name="interested">
                                <option value="info" id="info">Info Mail</option>
                                <option value="job" id="job">Job Mail</option>
                                <option value="project" id="project">Project Mail</option>
                             </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome" id="name" required >
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail *" id="email" required >
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="N° telefono" id="phone" required >
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Inserisci qui il tuo messaggio" id="message" required ></textarea>
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                            <div id="success"></div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-xl">Invia</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
```

Comment: have you set Email Preferences in config.php file

Comment: `$this->email->from($email, $name, $phone);` contains only from email id.

Comment: This code is perfectly working on CodeIgniter 2.2 and not on 3.0

Answer (score 0):

Your form inputs have an id set, but no name.

Your controller is looking to process the posted form values by name. But without the "name" value assigned in the inputs it won't work. You need to update your inputs like below.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome" name="name" id="name" required >
```